# Maximize the distance of projectile motion

Tags: calculus, projectile-motion

In a projectile motion, consider the projectile to be launched from $(0,0)$ as traced to be on cartesian axes. Then the trajectory is given by
$$y=x \tan \theta \big(1-x/R)$$
where $\theta$ is measured from $x$ axis , and gravity acts along $y$ axis, $R$ stands for the maximum range which may vary with the initial velocity which has a magnitude of $v$.

Using arc length formula of a general curve $\Gamma$,
$$\ell(\Gamma)=\int\sqrt{1+\left(\frac{dy}{dx}\right)^2}\ dx$$
we get the distance traversed as an integral of form $D=\sqrt{ax^2+bx+c}$.

An interactive model can be found [here.](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/jdxofl4vti)

I would like to know at what angle $\theta$ the distance travelled will be maximized, given a fixed $v$.
I tried doing
$$\frac{d}{d \theta}D=0$$ but it gave me an unknown $\frac{dx}{d \theta}$, I am unable to approach further, so I created a [graph here](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/m2qmi14fzs) which still doesn't helps to get a fixed value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The projectile equations are:

$$x=v\,\cos(\varphi)\,t\tag 1$$
$$y=v\,\sin(\varphi)\,t-\frac{1}{2}\,g\,t^2\tag 2$$

the arc length is:

$$L=\int_0^{t_f} \sqrt{\dot{x}^2+\dot{y}^2}\,dt$$

with $y=0~,\Rightarrow $ $t_f=\frac{2\,v\sin(\varphi)}{g}$

thus:

$$L=L(v~,\varphi)\tag 3$$

and the max arc length condition :

$$\frac{\partial L}{\partial \varphi}=\\\frac{v^2\,\cos(\varphi)}{g}\,\underbrace{(2+\ln  \left( -\sin \left( \varphi  \right) +1 \right) \sin \left( 
\varphi  \right) -\ln  \left( \sin \left( \varphi  \right) +1 \right) 
\sin \left( \varphi  \right) 
)}_{f(\varphi)}=0$$

$f(\varphi)=0~\Rightarrow~ \varphi=56.465^\circ$

*Remarks :*
I used Maple to do the calculations.